# Program to find ignored junits

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

Is there a program out there that can allow me to find all ignored junits?

By this I mean, I have seen unit tests that use the @Ignore and tests with method name like `ignore_testFoo()` or `xtestBar()` or `xxtestBar1()`, which all get ignored and they are very hard to find sometimes. 
I could grep for those cases, but I was wondering if there was an application that would find any of those situations automatically.

I tried using cobertura to obtain coverage on junits, to see which methods were being executed and which were not being executed, and picking apart the bad unit tests that was.

I was just wondering if there was a program or another method to obtain this information without hacking something up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A static analysis tool would serve you well here. [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) is a decent choice amongst them, it has a long list of [modules](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/availablechecks.html), and worst case you can easily write your own module to validate any coding convention you need.

You would locate or create a module for it then execute to find any non-conforming code.

***Edit***
[PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) looks to be an excellent choice to handle this task. It actually comes with a [set of JUnit rules](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/java/junit.html) already built in and its very easy to combine rules or create new ones.

Comment: Worst case I would just modify this PMD rule: http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/java/unusedcode.html#UnusedPrivateMethod to accept also public methods, and search for the @Ignore annotation.

Comment: Thanks for posting that link, I hadn't heard about PMD before. Interestingly, they have a bunch of prewritten rules for JUnit - http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/java/junit.html.

Comment: Note that the majority of these JUnit rules apply to JUnit 3, not JUnit 4

Comment: I will write a PMD rule.
@MAtthewFarwell- I understand that, but it couldn't hurt to start writing rules for junit4

Answer (score 1):

It should be easy to detect ignored tests using junit3 by a grep on your java test files. Find all lines matching test and parenthesis but with a method name that doesn't start by test.

For junit4, you could
* implement your own test runner by extending the default one, print out ignored tests
* build a small app that loads test classes, get all declared methods through introspect, print out those markedas ignored.

There may be a tool to do that, maybe even some runners already do, but actually it could take a few hours to have those tools from scratch if you really need them.